# Knockout Validation not clearing error template

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm having a little trouble using knockout.validation. I've currently got a user interface that looks a little like this:

[image]

The problem I've got is that the icons don't seem to disappear, even if there are no errors as reported by `viewModel.errors().length`, however the text does.

[image]

I'm using a custom template for my error, defined in JavaScript like so:

```
   // Setup knockout-validation
    ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
    ko.validation.configure({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: false,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: 'errorMessage'
    });

    /// extend objects
    viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
```

My error template is like so:

```
<!--This is the template for an error message that will be used by ko.validation - it should display an icon followed by the error message-->
<script id="errorMessage" type="text/html">
    <div class="validationMessage">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><em class="customMessage" data-bind='validationMessage: field'></em>
    </div>
</script>
```

I actually just removed from a data-bind from the `<i>` which has `data-bind="visible: field"` as this didn't seem to be working properly. I'm also not entirely sure where `field` comes from - it may be a ko.validation property that I've forgotten. It meant the icon displayed still even when there was no error, but prevent the icon displaying when the field was empty so I had a `"This field is required"` message with no icon.

My validation object which gets extended to my observable looks like:

```
validation : { required: true, number: true }
```

A look at my viewModel during execution:

[image]

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong to prevent these icons disappearing? I could manually remove them using jQuery but I'm hesitant to do so without fully understanding the problem.

Comment: Can you please explain what was the problem with the `data-bind="visible: field"`? Which version of the validation plugin are you using? Because both the cdnjs and the nuget version are quite outdated and full of bugs...

Comment: @nemesv THink I'm using 1.0.2 from cdnjs. If the extra data bind is there then the icon still remains even with no error message, but the icon disappears if the field value is empty but the error message 'this field is required' appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually managed to find the resolution to this via a fiddle I stumbled across. The `data-bind="visible: field"` bit that I took out is the all important aspect. It seems `field` is the knockout validation item in context (which is why I couldn't figure out where it came from).

Binding directly to `field` however is wrong, this is simply binding to the value of the field which explains why it's alway there unless you provide an empty value. Knockout validation however has extended the object to include some additional functions. Specifically `field.isValid()` is the important call and can be used in the binding instead.

```
data-bind="visible: field.isValid()"
```

Comment: Could you please fixe the link

Comment: The answer is clear, sometimes sample is the simplest answer. If you can't restore the link could you please correct the answer, remove the link etc :)